# Call JS Function inside an Object

Tags: javascript

I am new to OO in JavaScript and trying to make this simple canvas demo:

```
var c; // typeof c is the canvas element
function SolarSystem(plane, sun) {

    this.plane = plane; // typeof plane is Canvas Ctxt
    this.sun = sun;

    this.init = function () {
        draw();
    }


    this.render = function () {
        c.height = c.height;
        requestAnimationFrame(this.render);
        this.draw();
    }

    this.draw = function () {
        console.log(1);
    }

}
```

What I want to do is, to render `SolarSystem`, I want to call render() that is inside of it. I cannot call render() from render(), how can I do that without getting `Uncaught TypeError: Type error` in the console? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typically what's used in objects is this little line:

```
var self = this;
```

because `this` changes depending on the scope you're in, `self` makes it very easy to reference the original object. Then, when you need something off the `SolarSystem()` object, you can reference it using `self.method()`.

You may not see the benefits in your example, but if/when you began applying scope to your methods you'll see how it's useful. e.g.

```
function MyObject(){
  var self = this;

  var private = function(){
  };
  this.Public = function(){
    // try it at home:
    // call      `self.private();`
    // then call `this.private();`
  };
}
```

Comment: @Ian, requestAnimationFrame(callback) is optimized for canvas animations.

Comment: @NullGeo I'm not sure what the point of that comment was. All I was saying was `setTimeout` is a good example of losing scope that people get tricked by

Answer (score 3):

```
this.init = function () {
    draw();
}
```

`draw()` should be `this.draw()` otherwise the function is called through the global `window` object.

Comment: That was also one of the problems, but it's weird that Google Chrome showed problem in the line `requestAnimationFrame(this.render);`. Thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as told by said by Brad Christie I was referring to the local scope of the function by saying this and not the object SolarSystem. The following worked perfect. Thanks again!

```
function SolarSystem(plane, sun){

this.plane = plane;
this.sun = sun;

var self = this;

this.init = function(){
    self.draw();
}


this.render = function(){
    c.height = c.height; // reset canvas
    requestAnimationFrame(self.render);
    self.draw();
}

this.draw = function(){
    console.log(1);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting an answer? Just click the check next to the one that solved your issue.

Comment: @sillylittleme, I posted the answer so that other users could see how I fixed it. I don't want others to have this issue: http://xkcd.com/979/
:D
Also, I marked one of them as answers.